# How can I use auth cookie in cookie Aware Client to access secured web page?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, cookies

Initially I'm login in to a secured webpage,then m getting the cookie manually and then i have to set the cookie while making another call to fetch data from authorized web url.
how can I make one cookie aware client which do not require to set the auth cookie again and again. it should automatically set the auth cookie and get the required data.

My code is

```
CPSession retVal = null;
        if (guid != "")
            retVal = TokenManager.getSessionInfo(guid);

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate
        { return true; };

        HttpWebRequest httpWReq =
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        httpWReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bdata = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        httpWReq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        httpWReq.Method = "PUT";
        httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWReq.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri(address), retVal.getAttributeValue(CookieType));  // here I'm setting cookie manually.

        httpWReq.ContentLength = bdata.Length;

        Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(bdata, 0, bdata.Length);
        stream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
        string s = response.ToString();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one cookie aware client like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace SunPowerService.Service
{
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer m_container = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = m_container;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
}
```

and you can call it like this

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri("YourUrlToGetAuthCookie");
                    client.m_container.SetCookies(uri, strCookieVal);
                    jsonresponse = client.DownloadString(uri);
                }
```